# Problem with continuous bibliography numbering for thesis chapters

Tags: bibliographies, numbering, natbib, counters

I am having the problem of a continuous numbering of bibliography in my PhD thesis. That is, if the bibliography of Chapter 1 goes from [[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xj60l.jpg)],...,[3], in Chapter 2 it starts from [4],...[6] like below.

[image][image]

I have provided a MWE of my thesis below. I am using multiple .tex files for each chapter.

Thesis.tex file =>

```
\documentclass[11pt]{report}

\usepackage[a4paper,left=35mm, right=25mm, top=19mm,bottom=23mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{setspace}
\doublespacing
\usepackage[nottoc]{tocbibind}
\usepackage[titletoc]{appendix}
\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{multibib}
\usepackage[round, sort, numbers, authoryear, sectionbib]{natbib}
\usepackage[sectionbib]{chapterbib}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{bibentry}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{amsthm,amsmath,amsfonts,amssymb,bbm}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{graphics}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[pdfencoding=auto, psdextra]{hyperref}
\hypersetup{colorlinks=true,linkcolor=blue, anchorcolor=red, citecolor=blue, filecolor = red, urlcolor = blue,
            pdfauthor=author}
\pdfstringdefDisableCommands{\def\varepsilon{\textepsilon}}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage{bookmark}
\usepackage{array, booktabs, makecell}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{xurl}
\usepackage[misc]{ifsym}
\sisetup{table-number-alignment=center, exponent-product=\cdot}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween}
\usepackage{subfig}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.10}
\usepackage{comment}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{listings}
\definecolor{mygreen}{rgb}{0,0.6,0}
\definecolor{mygray}{rgb}{0.5,0.5,0.5}
\definecolor{mymauve}{rgb}{0.58,0,0.82}

\newcounter{bibcount}
\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\@lbibitem}{\item[}{\item[\hfil\stepcounter{bibcount}{\thebibcount.}}{}{}
\setlength{\bibhang}{2\parindent}
\renewcommand\NAT@bibsetup%
[1]{\setlength{\leftmargin}{\bibhang}\setlength{\itemindent}{-\parindent}%
    \setlength{\itemsep}{\bibsep}\setlength{\parsep}{\z@}}

\lstset{ 
    backgroundcolor=\color{white},   % choose the background color; you must add \usepackage{color} or \usepackage{xcolor}; should come as last argument
    basicstyle=\linespread{0.5},        % the size of the fonts that are used for the code
    breakatwhitespace=false,         % sets if automatic breaks should only happen at whitespace
    breaklines=true,                 % sets automatic line breaking
    captionpos=b,                    % sets the caption-position to bottom
    commentstyle=\color{mygreen},    % comment style
    deletekeywords={...},            % if you want to delete keywords from the given language
    %escapeinside={\%*}{*)},          % if you want to add LaTeX within your code
    extendedchars=true,              % lets you use non-ASCII characters; for 8-bits encodings only, does not work with UTF-8
    %frame=single,                     % adds a frame around the code
    keepspaces=true,                 % keeps spaces in text, useful for keeping indentation of code (possibly needs columns=flexible)
    keywordstyle=\color{blue},       % keyword style
    language=Octave,                 % the language of the code
    morekeywords={*,...},            % if you want to add more keywords to the set
    % numbers=left,                    % where to put the line-numbers; possible values are (none, left, right)
    numbersep=5pt,                   % how far the line-numbers are from the code
    numberstyle=\tiny\color{mygray}, % the style that is used for the line-numbers
    rulecolor=\color{black},         % if not set, the frame-color may be changed on line-breaks within not-black text (e.g. comments (green here))
    showspaces=false,                % show spaces everywhere adding particular underscores; it overrides 'showstringspaces'
    showstringspaces=false,          % underline spaces within strings only
    showtabs=false,                  % show tabs within strings adding particular underscores
    stepnumber=2,                    % the step between two line-numbers. If it's 1, each line will be numbered
    stringstyle=\color{mymauve},     % string literal style
    tabsize=2,                     % sets default tabsize to 2 spaces
    title=\lstname                   % show the filename of files included with \lstinputlisting; also try caption instead of title
}

\lstdefinestyle{customc}{
    belowcaptionskip=1\baselineskip,
    breaklines=true,
    frame=L,
    xleftmargin=\parindent,
    language=C,
    showstringspaces=false,
    basicstyle=\footnotesize\ttfamily,
    keywordstyle=\bfseries\color{green!40!black},
    commentstyle=\itshape\color{purple!40!black},
    identifierstyle=\color{blue},
    stringstyle=\color{orange},
}

\lstdefinestyle{customasm}{
    belowcaptionskip=1\baselineskip,
    xleftmargin=\parindent,
    language=[x86masm]Assembler,
    basicstyle=\footnotesize\ttfamily,
    commentstyle=\itshape\color{purple!40!black},
}

\newtheorem{cond}{Condition}{\bfseries}{\itshape}
\numberwithin{cond}{chapter}
\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem{definition}{Definition}
\numberwithin{definition}{chapter}
\newtheorem{remark}{Remark}
\numberwithin{remark}{chapter}
\theoremstyle{plain}
\newtheorem{notation}{Notation}
\newtheorem{proposition}{Proposition}
\newtheorem{assumption}{Assumption}
\numberwithin{assumption}{chapter}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}
\numberwithin{theorem}{chapter}
\newtheorem{lemma}{Lemma}
\numberwithin{lemma}{chapter}
\newtheorem{corollary}{Corollary}
\newcommand{\lfrac}[2]{\genfrac{}{}{0pt}{}{#1}{#2}}

\newtheorem{Example}{Example}
\numberwithin{Example}{chapter}
\newenvironment{example}{%
    \vspace{0.3cm} \pagebreak [2]%
    \par%
    \refstepcounter{proposition}%
    \noindent%
    {\bf  Example~\theproposition.\ }}{\qed}%
    %
\newenvironment{proof1}{%
    \vspace{0.3cm} \pagebreak [2]%
    \par%
    \noindent%
    {\it Proof~}}{\qed}%
    %

\def\a{\alpha}
\def\be{\beta}
\def\de{\delta}
\def\De{\Delta}
\def\t{{\bf t}}
\def\ga{\gamma}
\def\Ga{\Gamma}
\def\la{\lambda}
\def\La{\Lambda}
\def\ep{\varepsilon}
\def\si{\sigma}
\def\e{\eta}
\def\th{\theta}
\def\o{\omega}
\def\u{{\overline u}}
%\def\O{\Omega}
\def\cov{{\rm Cov}}
\def\diam{{\rm diam}}
\def\dim{{\rm dim}_{_{\rm H}}}
\def\Dim{{\rm dim}_{_{\rm P}}}
\def\adim{{\rm adim}}
\def\aDim{{\rm aDim}}
\def\sp{{\rm supp}}
\def\var{{\rm Var}}


\def\l{{\langle}}
\def\r{\rangle}

\def\F{{\EuScript F}}
\def\In{{\rm 1 \hskip-2.9truept l}}
\def\OCC{{\mathbb{O}}}
\newcommand{\wh}{\widehat}
\newcommand{\wt}{\widetilde}
\def\N{{\mathbb N}}
\def\R{{\mathbb R}}
\def\Q{{\mathbb Q}}
\def\C{{\mathbb C}}
\def\eps{\varepsilon}
\def\Re {{\rm Re}\,}
\def\E{{\mathbb E}}
\def\I{{\cal I}}
\def\P{{\mathbb P}}
\def\Z{{\mathbb Z}}
\def\M{{\EuScript M}}
\def\EN{{\EuScript{E}}}
\def\CAP{{\EuScript{C}}}
\def\sleq{\mathop{\preccurlyeq}}
\def\sgeq{\mathop{\succcurlyeq}}
\def\kto{{\cal K}}
\def\K{{\cal K}_{j_0}}
\def\H{{\cal H}_{l}^q}
\def\V{{\cal V}}
\def\ovl{\overline}
\def\wh{\widehat}

\title{\LARGE{\bf{Working Draft}} \\
    {Anomaly Detection}\\
    {\large Hello}\\
    }
    
\author{Anonymous}
\date{16.11.2020}

\begin{document}

%\maketitle
\begin{titlepage}
    \vspace*{1cm}
    \centering
    
    {\Huge\bfseries \bf{Working Draft ...} \\ \huge{Anomaly Detection} \par}

\end{titlepage}

\tableofcontents

\listoffigures

\listoftables

\chapter*{Abstract}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Abstract}

This is my abstract.

\chapter*{Acknowledgements}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Acknowledgements}

Thank you all.

\include{Introduction}

\include{Definitions}

\end{document}

Next, the Introduction.tex file =>



 \chapter{Introduction}\label{Chapter1}
    
    This chapter gives Introduction
    
    \section{Data science}\label{SI:1}
    
    Anomaly detection plays an important role in today's world, see~\cite{Chandola:2009},\cite{Patcha:2007},\cite{Akoglu:2015}.
    
    \bibliographystyle{plainnat}
    \bibliography{BibInt}
```

Next, the Definitions.tex file =>

```
\chapter{Definitions, notations and auxiliary results }\label{Chapter2}

Anomaly detection plays an important role in today's world, see~\cite{Chandola:2009},\cite{Patcha:2007},\cite{Akoglu:2015}.

\bibliographystyle{plainnat}
\bibliography{BibInt}
```

Finally, the .bib file =>

```
@article{Chandola:2009,
  title = {Anomaly detection: A survey},
  author = {Chandola, Varun and Banerjee, Arindam and Kumar, Vipin},
  journal = {ACM computing surveys (CSUR)},
  volume = {41},
  number = {3},
  pages = {1-58},
  year = {2009},
  }
  
@article{Patcha:2007,
  title = {An overview of anomaly detection techniques: Existing solutions and latest technological trends},
  author = {Patcha, Animesh and Park, Jung-Min},
  journal = {Computer networks},
  volume = {51},
  number = {12},
  pages = {3448-3470},
  year = {2007}
  }  
  
@article{Akoglu:2015,
  title = {Graph based anomaly detection and description: a survey},
  author = {Akoglu, Leman and Tong, Hanghang and Koutra, Danai},
  journal = {Data mining and knowledge discovery},
  volume = {29},
  number = {3},
  pages = {626-688},
  year = {2015}
  }
```

I have spent many days trying to fix this issue. I need each bibliography to start from "1". I would really appreciate your help on this matter.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You already define a `bibcount` counter to display the numbers in the bibliography. Therefore, you can reset this counter to 0 after each `\include` using `\setcounter{bibcount}{0}`.

MWE:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{report}

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage[round, sort, numbers, authoryear, sectionbib]{natbib}
\usepackage[sectionbib]{chapterbib}
\usepackage{bibentry}

\newcounter{bibcount}
\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\@lbibitem}{\item[}{\item[\hfil\stepcounter{bibcount}{\thebibcount.}}{}{}
\setlength{\bibhang}{2\parindent}
\renewcommand\NAT@bibsetup%
[1]{\setlength{\leftmargin}{\bibhang}\setlength{\itemindent}{-\parindent}%
    \setlength{\itemsep}{\bibsep}\setlength{\parsep}{\z@}}

\begin{document}
\include{bibIntroduction}
\setcounter{bibcount}{0}
\include{bibDefinitions}
\end{document}
```

Note that I removed `\usepackage{multibib}` from the MWE because it is not necessary (the multiple bibliographies are handled by the `chapterbib` package).

Result:

[image]

Comment: Perfect !! :) Thank you very much @Marijn  for solving this issue. This answer solved my problem. Much appreciated.